# Read data from a file and assign them to variables

Tags: c#, file

I need to read data from a file, so I have this code.

```
public static void readData()
{
    TextReader readFile;
    string chain;
    bool found = false;
    string[] fields = new string[2];
    char[] breakUp = { ':' };

    try
    {     
        readFile = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\unam\\Documents\\Hugo\\Datos.txt");

        chain = readFile.ReadLine();
        while (chain != null)
        {
            fields = chain.Split(breakUp);


            if (fields[0].Trim().Equals("Name"))
            {
                name = fields[1].Trim();            
            }
            else
            {
                if (fields[0].Trim().Equals("Age"))
                {
                    Age = fields[1].Trim();    
                }
            }
            readFile.Close();

         }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("¡File not found!" + fe.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("¡File not found!" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

And in the document I have

- Name: Hugo
- Age: 23

When I execute the code it stays in a loop in the first if so it just reads the name again and again, my question is, how can I get out of that loop to read the other data?

Comment: You need to keep reading lines into `chain`. Don't let it stay the same value or nothing changes.

Comment: chain = readFile.ReadLine(); Should be in while section

Comment: Also, you should be wrapping your `StreamReader`/`TextReader` in a `using` block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the string you read each time:

```
       chain = readFile.ReadLine();
       while (chain != null)
       {
           fields = chain.Split(breakUp);


           if (fields[0].Trim().Equals("Name"))
           {
                name = fields[1].Trim();
           }
           else
           {
               if (fields[0].Trim().Equals("Age"))
               {
                    Age = fields[1].Trim();
               }
            }
       chain = readFile.ReadLine(); // <--
       }
       readFile.Close();
```

As pointed out by [Broots Waymb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2957232/broots-waymb) you can put the read into the while-condition as well:

```
       while ((chain = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           fields = chain.Split(breakUp);


           if (fields[0].Trim().Equals("Name"))
           {
                name = fields[1].Trim();
           }
           else
           {
               if (fields[0].Trim().Equals("Age"))
               {
                    Age = fields[1].Trim();
               }
            }
       }
       readFile.Close();
```

Comment: You can simplify this a little bit by doing `while ((chain = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)` and removing the 2 `chain = readFile.ReadLine();` lines.

Comment: I tried to make as little changes to the code as possible, but as this is a good improvement, I'll add it

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to check when you have reached to the end of the file, refer [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8)

```
             using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
```